# The jQuery AJAX load.() method isn't working for me, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to load text from a .txt file into an HTML document using the load() method but I can't find the problem in my code. The text file is on the desktop along with my html document. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#nav1').click(function(){
                    $('#target').load('textfile.txt');
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="#" id="nav1"> Load Button </a>
        <div id="target"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

All I have in **"textfile.txt"** is the following:

```
<h1> Heading 1 </h1>
<p> Some paragraph text. </p>
```

Comment: where is 'content' id

Comment: $('#target').load('textfile.txt');

Comment: Try what ARUN said, and if that does not resolve it, could you specify what the error is that you're getting when you try this.

Comment: It doesn't give me an error, it just does nothing.

Comment: Nicola Daaboul   you specified wrong id

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, you need to prevent de click event
 use `e.preventDfeault()`

```
        <body>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#nav1').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault()
                        $('#content').load('textfile.txt');
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <a href="#" id="nav1"> Load Button </a>
            <div id="content"></div>
        </body>
```

Note you need to use a server when you are doing ajax

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Nicola Daaboul try this:

```
 <html>      
    <head>
        <script>
        function loadDoc() {
                  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                    }
                  };
                  xhttp.open("GET", "textfile.txt", true);
                  xhttp.send();
                }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <a href="#" onclick="loadDoc()"> Load Button </a>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Actually your click() is not working for your condition. so it can be done by above code it will definitely works for you.

Comment: why did you load jquery when you just use vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works absolutely fine. There are some common mistakes probably because you're not able to get your code, working. So, make sure you have done the following things:

- jQuery file is included before your function wrap.
- Make sure the textfile.txt is in the same    directory where your
  script resides. If not, specify the correct path.
- Double check there are no other elements with id    `nav1` and
  `target`.

When working with js files always refer to the console tab of developer tools, you might probably find solutions yourself.